# About Anselm's Ontological Argument and Bertrand Russell

Tags: ontology, bertrand-russell

Did Bertrand Russell read and analyse Anselm's Ontological Argument and if so did he have anything positive to say about it?

Comment: Can a set of processes be said to exist ? Speaking biologically an individual can be partly described as a set of processes. Therefore could one say an individual has the property of existence , in this situation?

Comment: Did Russell find it easy or hard to criticize Anselm's arguments?

Answer (score 1):

He did. Read the relevant chapter of his "History of Philosophy". I don't have it with me, but I seem to recall that his criticism of the argument centers around the fact that Anselm treats existence was a (first-order) predicate. Russell thinks this is nonsense.

Russell's wrong. There are perfectly cogent ways of representing existence as first-order, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: Such ways don't rescue Anselm's argument, however.

Comment: Yes; Russell's criticism is along Frege's analysis of *existence* as a "second-level" property. I.e. *existence* is not a property of *individuals* but of *concepts*, like number. In the phrase "the seven planets" we are **not** ascribing the number seven to the individual planets, but to the concept "satellite of the sun". Similarly, when we say that "the King of France exists", we are not "predicating" existence of an individual, but asserting that the concept "King of France" is *instantiated* (i.e.there is an individual which "fall under" that concept).

Comment: @RexKerr I haven't read much of this literature. Do you know of a particularly good paper on the topic? Klima seems to disagree with you: http://faculty.fordham.edu/klima/FILES/Anselm-PHRU1000.pdf

Comment: see note 2 on page six of the above.

Comment: @shane - Klima makes the point I would: by treating thoughts instead of actuality, you needn't worry about the existence-predicate, but only conclude that the God that you think exists you think is greater (in the sense of doing good) than the God that you don't think exists.  This doesn't require God to exist or even for you to think that God exists; you just observe that the hypothetical you that believes God exists is the one that has in mind a being that can do no greater good.  (And even that's a little sketchy, because of the wandering back and forth between the hypothetical and actual.)

Comment: Right. It isn't the existence that is the problem with Anselm. Like Aquinas, Klima thinks the argument is sound, just unpersuasive because the unbeliever does not have to admit that the concept of that than which none greater exists is instantiated.

Comment: So Anselm's arguments have been totally discredited?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go that far. there are contemporary ontological arguments inspired by anselm that might be sound, as far as I know. Not an expert here though.

Comment: Are there forms of Anselm's arguments that might convince a non-expert or even an 'average Joe'  ( to use a slang) interested in arguments for a benevolent Dirty?